# Javascript && operator logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, and-operator

I'm developing a controller in angular. For some reason there is an If statement that is giving me a issue, yes an if statement.

The code is the following:

```
$scope.new = function(logoFile) {
if($scope.comprobarCampoDesc() && $scope.comprobarCampoFecha() && $scope.comprobarCampoName() ) 
{ 
//program logic
}
```

Also there is the other pieces of code:

```
$scope.comprobarCampoName = function(e) {
//program logic
return bol;
};


$scope.comprobarCampoDesc = function(e) {
//program logic
return bol;
};


$scope.comprobarCampoFecha = function(e) {
//program logic
return bol;
};
```

Ok, For any reason that I'm not able to identify, the if statement only checks 2 of 3 methods, depending of the order. In this concrete case it is ignoring "$scope.comprobarCampoName" but if I change the order other method is witch doesn't work.

Thanks for the help.
Greetings.

Comment: Does it always check 2 of 3 methods or only if 2 of 3 methods are returning `true` ?

Comment: well you must know the `&&` operator only evaluates the next operand( `functions` in you case ) only if the operand before evaluates to true or equivalent.

Comment: It's strange because all of the operands are false and allways execute 2 of them. Anyway thanks for the help. Finally I join the three methos in one in order to do only one call in the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, if one of the conditions is equal to `false`, the `if` statement stops and does not iterate further.

If you really need to execute each of those, I recommend you to do the following :

```
var first = $scope.comprobarCampoDesc();
var second = $scope.comprobarCampoName();
var third = $scope.comprobarCampoFecha();

if (first && second && third){
   // execute
}
```

Comment: The official term for this behavior, which is very common in programming languages, is *Short-Circuit Evalution*. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators